# R: Subset a data.frame based on column of a second data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sqldf

Suppose there are two 2 datasets and a user wants to get all rows from first that are in second.

First dataset is mtcars and second is "data" like this (for demo purposes, imagine large sets)

```
data <- data.frame(colA=c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6),colB='foo')
```

How in dplyr or base R I can achieve the same result as with this SQL command:

```
sqldf("select * from mtcars where cyl in (select distinct colA from data)")
```

imagine that both data sets have more than 100k rows ! so dplyr and fast solution is preferred.

The correct result is

```
> sqldf("select * from mtcars where cyl in (select distinct colA from data)")
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
6  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
7  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
8  19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
9  17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
10 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
11 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
12 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
13 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
14 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
15 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
16 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
17 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
18 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: may be `mtcars[1:nrow(mtcars) %in% data[,1],]`  In `mtcars` rownames are not numbers

Comment: assume both columns are strings or need to be cast to string

Comment: Why not simply: `mtcars[ mtcars$cyl %in% unique(data$colA),]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>% filter(cyl %in% data[,1])
```

Comment: it should list all rows from mtcars where cylinder is 4 or 6. The correct results has many more rows.